# Привязка аккаунта telegram к пользователю на сайте. Проект на ruby on rails 6

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Такой вопрос. Есть проект на ruby on rails 6: сайт с новостями. Пользователи реализованы с помощью гемаа devise. Нужно сделать так, чтобы аккаунт сайта привязать к аккаунту телеграмм. Это нужно для дальнейшего взаимодействия с ботом. Есть мб предложения какие?